# Why is not my Xcode build shown in TestFlight tab of Apple's App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, testflight

I don't see my build kPdiag8 within App Store Connect > TestFlight tab's build list.

Step 1. I created a test app in Xcode then built > archived > dist > did "auto manage signing" > upload.

Step 2. Then went to: App Store Connect > Apps > opened my app auto-generated by Xcode > clicked TestFlight tab > no builds.

Step 3. And few days later, still no build.

[image]

UPDATE 25APR2022...
The Bundle ID from my new Xcode app is not in Bundle ID dropdown at: app Store Connect > Apps > New App > Bundle ID .

But doing Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Add App ID > enter desc, bundle ID > Continue > Register I get error:
"An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value
An App ID with Identifier '' is not available."

Comment: It might take some time until it appears in the TestFlight tab, when did you performed the upload?

Comment: Last week.  Still no upload, as of today.  Am I missing an important step?